# DH table for a 4 DOF Scara Robot

Tags: kinematics

Kinda bangin my head here trying to make a DH table for a robot. So I found a 4 DOF Scara robot online and am trying to make a DH table for that robot just with different link lengths.

1. Would the DH table have 3 rows or 4? I don't understand how 4 is possible, but I am not so sure
2. Would theta 1 be 0 or a variable? since joint 2 rotates (x1,y1,z1)? From what i understand theta1 is the angle between X0 and X1 about Z0, so ig it could vary?
3. Does the rest look right in the diagram and the DH table

Any help would really be appriciated. Thank you!

Here's a picture of the robot

[image]

Here's the robot manipulator diagram I came up with.

[image]

And here's my DH table so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you miss the end-effector frame.
You can try to practice more textbook examples(with answers) to be familiar with DH.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did not add that, and that was intentional, beacuse from what I knew, there only supposed to be a frame for joints that are connected by links. i.e. Rotary joints, Prismatic joints.. etc. Isn't it?

Comment: @Crab00189 "fixed joint" is also a type of joint... if you want to solve for end effector position, you'll need to model that somehow.